# Laravel doesn't see methods in Policy class

Tags: laravel, authorization, policy, authorize

I've done everything from documentation, lesson from laracasts, youtube lesson and etc and can't understand why method from Policy class didn't call
Laravel Framework 7.12.0

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\User;

use App\Policies\UserPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
         //'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\Article' => 'App\Policies\ArticlePolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $this->registerPolicies();

    }
}







<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Article;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ArticlePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Article  $article
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Article $article)
    {
        dd('It must be called but ...');
        return true;
    }
}







    public function index()
    {
        $article = new Article();
//        if (Gate::allows('update',$article)){
//
//            dd('Not work too');
//        }
        $this->authorize('update',$article);
        
        return view('home', compact('user'));
    }
```

When I use authorize or Gate::allows - nothing happens
I even tried to add my model in array $policies, but as I realized it doesn't necessary if path and name Model and Policy is correct

Method update doesn't call, why?

by the way - if I write construct in Policy class - it's working, but problem with calling method not solved

Comment: Show the policy and how you call authorize please :)

Comment: why $this->authorize not Gate::authorize ?

Comment: Scroll down code block please, it has problem with scroll I suppose, I added my Policy and calling authorize

Comment: Gate::authorize and $this->authorize are the same things, but anyway I tried, didn't help